# Format a number string

Tags: java, string, number-formatting

I have a number `String` like `"1234567890"`.

I need to format this `String` into `"1234 5678 90"`. (The blank spaces are SPACE character) 
Could somebody tell me on how to do this in java?

Thanks

Comment: You should write a program :)

Comment: I think there is a mass confusion and why he is getting `-1`. He is not asking for basic string manipulation but number formatting which is a complicated thing to do in Java (see Baadshah's answer). Albeit he could have googled this question has it has been asked a myriad of times.

Comment: @AdamGent Ok, I like that answer too, but come on... if you stucked somewhere, you ask Stackoverflow. If you have a solution and you need better, ask Stackoverflow. Not if you didn't even start to think of the problem.

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary Yes its has gotten ridiculous. My favorite is people asking why something is slow with out giving any benchmark numbers or code. The FAQ should be to teach someone how to use Google :)

Comment: @Sen that looks like a phone number. If it is you should look at Google's phone number library: https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/

Comment: Actually I thought about this. But dint have any idea or working experience on RegEx or DecimalFormatSymbols.. So only I thought about posting it in StackOverflow. @Adam Gent: Thanks for the support. I even thought this was a really dumb question, and so I voted for closing this. :-)

Comment: @AdamGent This is not for Phone number.. It is for STB smart card number display.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your strings are all of the same length:

```
String s1 = "1234567890";
String s2 = s1.substring(0, 3) + " " + s1.substring(4, 7) + " " + s1.substring(8, 9);
```

Comment: Very slow!! Substring will parse the String from the beginning everytime it is called.

Comment: @javadev Very slow compared to what?

Comment: Compared to nothing. The solution works fine, but : 1) will not work if you have a bigger number and 2) will be very slow if it is a huge one.

Comment: @javadev If, for example, the substring goes from index 0 to index 3, it will only ever read those characters in between.

Comment: @javadev Decimal formatting is far more expensive.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sorry monday morning. I corrected it... especially since it not very PC.

Answer (score 1):

```
   StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder("1234567890");
   sb.insert(4, ' ').insert(9, ' ');
   String output= sb.toString();
```

Comment: What is phoneNumberSymbols?

Comment: Have you read doc for DecimalFormat?You tried your code?

Comment: +1 for idea though hardly myformat.format works

Comment: @Baadshah did u actually run this to see the result?

Comment: Your solution does not work correctly. See https://ideone.com/jVwvaQ. I don't know why people upvote only because it looks fancy

Comment: Thanks you all for the feedback.I edited my answer with basic string builder as my guess from docs with Decimal format not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Regex based version

```
     String s = "1234567890";
     s = s.replaceAll("(\\d+)(\\d{2})", "$1 $2");
     while(s.matches("\\d+\\d{4} \\d+")) {
         s = s.replaceAll("(\\d+)(\\d{4} \\d+)", "$1 $2");
     }
     System.out.println(s);
```

output

1234 5678 90

Answer (score 1):

You could use `StringBuilder` for performance :

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("1234567890");
builder.insert(4, ' ').insert(9, ' ');
String formattedString = builder.toString();
```

gives you

```
1234 5678 90
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `java.text.MessageFormat`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String phoneRawString = "1234567890";

    java.text.MessageFormat phoneMsgFmt = new java.text.MessageFormat(
            "{0} {1} {2}");
    // suposing a grouping of 4-4-2
    String[] phoneNumArr = { phoneRawString.substring(0, 4),
            phoneRawString.substring(4, 8), phoneRawString.substring(8) };

    System.out.println(phoneMsgFmt.format(phoneNumArr));
}
```

Output:

```
1234 5678 90
```

Another way using regex:

```
long phoneNum = 1234567890L;
String result = String.valueOf(phoneNum).replaceFirst("(\\d{4})(\\d{4})(\\d+)", "$1 $2 $3");
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: SubString method will be a little slow.

Comment: @Sen See another way using regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String input = "1234567890";
    Formatter f = new Formatter(new StringBuilder(), Locale.UK);
    String res = f.format("%s%5s%3s", input.substring(0, 4), input.substring(4, 8), input.substring(8, 10)).toString();
    System.out.println(res);
```